# Error creating Liquid Map on Azure with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, liquid

I'm trying to create a Liquid Map on Azure using Terraform trough the resource "azurerm_logic_app_integration_account_map" but I'm getting the error saying that the Liquid needs a content-type "text/plain" to be set.

> Message="The 'contentType' property of map 'templateResponse' of type 'Liquid' must be set to 'text/plain'."

I've already tried to add the contentType to the resource properties but it is unknown to Terraform.

> An argument named "contentType" is not expected here.

What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
resource "azurerm_logic_app_integration_account_map" "templateRequest" {
  name                     = "templateRequest"
  resource_group_name      = local.platform_core_rg
  integration_account_name = local.integration_account_name
  map_type                 = "Liquid"
  content                  = file("${path.module}/liquid/templateRequest.liquid")
}
```

Comment: Is the file bigger than 2MB? If that is the case, I think something different needs to be done: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/maps/create-or-update.

Comment: The file is just 1 KB :/

Comment: Are you sure that the file is in the root directory of the module?

Comment: Yes. The file is read by Terraform and on the plan phase it doesn't detect any error. Is on the Deploy phase that Azure complains that the contentType is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug over the Azurerm plugin that has been solved.

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/15350